# Inside the package, I must use the Facade Pattern (or something similar)?

Tags: java, package, facade

I'm using a Facade to access the methods and classes inside package, but and inside the package? I must access the methods of other class directly or by a facade or something similar?

Example: `Package 1(Class Foo, Class Bar, Facade FooBar)`

`Outside Class -> FooBar --> Foo method`

but inside:

`Foo --> Bar` or `Foo --> FooBar --> Bar`[image: Facade]

Comment: wait..what?! could you please elaborate a bit? i have a hard time understanding the question

Comment: Look at image now. Is better Foo acces the method of Bar directly or via the Facade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A facade is a single interface which allows easy access to all the functionality going on behind the scenes.  It is not the same thing as a requirement to pass internal functionality between components back out of the system (and back into it through the interface).

Facades are control panels, they simplify and hide the internal components so external users don't get lost in the complexity of what is behind the interface.  An interface with internal components that reaches back outside and manipulates itself through the interface would make a good art presentation, but would be a lousy Facade, as it would expose that which is it trying to hide.

```
Outside -> Facade -> Inside.
```

not

```
Outside -> Facade -> Inside -> Facade -> Inside.
```

or in your case

```
OutSide -> FooBar -> Foo -> Bar
```

would be just fine.